# Why my data from MySql Database are not showing in the application?

Tags: android, mysql, flutter, dart

Created an API using PHP for fetching the data from MySql database but my data isn't showing in my flutter app. I created the model class for the JSON file and called the file.
I need to show the data in my app the page Homescreen.dart but the data are not fetching.

this is my JSON file

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Cafe La Vista",
        "Address": "Zindabazar",
        "Longitude": "91.878357",
        "Latitude": "24.896719"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Peepers",
        "Address": "Zindabazar",
        "Longitude": "91.871094",
        "Latitude": "24.895376"
    }
]
```

This is my model class for fetching data from mysql

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<restaurant_list> restaurantsFromJson(String str) =>
    List<restaurant_list>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => restaurant_list.fromJson(x)));

String restaurantsToJson(List<restaurant_list> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class restaurant_list {
  restaurant_list({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.address,
    this.longitude,
    this.latitude,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String address;
  String longitude;
  String latitude;

  factory restaurant_list.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      restaurant_list(
        id: json["Id"],
        name: json["Name"],
        address: json["Address"],
        longitude: json["Longitude"],
        latitude: json["Latitude"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Id": id,
        "Name": name,
        "Address": address,
        "Longitude": longitude,
        "Latitude": latitude,
      };
}
```

In this class called the API

```
import 'restaurant_list.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<restaurant_list>> fetchRestaurants() async {
  String url = "https://sylrest.000webhostapp.com/conn.php";
  final response = await http.get(url);
  return restaurantsFromJson(response.body);
}
```

The HomePage where the data should be shown

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'restaurant_list.dart';
import 'restaurant_list_api.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('HomeScreen'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchRestaurants(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    restaurant_list restaurant = snapshot.data[index];
                    return Text('${restaurant.name}');
                  });
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you print the response? like is it showing there?

Comment: the response is just showing the Circular progress indicator. That means my data are not in the snapshot.

Comment: these are the when I printed snapshot error.                                                        I/flutter (13344): null
I/flutter (13344): Error on line 1, column 5: Invalid media type: expected "/".
I/flutter (13344):   ╷
I/flutter (13344): 1 │ JSON
I/flutter (13344):   │     ^
I/flutter (13344):   ╵

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the json data you are fitching.
I have added some code here :

```dart
Future<List<restaurant_list>> fetchRestaurants() async {
  String url = "https://sylrest.000webhostapp.com/conn.php";
  final response = await http.get(url);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```